# How to check if Postfix was compiled with support for Dovecot SASL?

Tags: postfix, installation, dovecot, sasl, debian-jessie

The [Dovecot](http://wiki.dovecot.org/HowTo/PostfixAndDovecotSASL) instructions state:

> Since version 2.3, Postfix supports SMTP AUTH through Dovecot SASL as
>   introduced in the Dovecot 1.0 series. If using Postfix obtained from a
>   binary (such as a .rpm or .deb file), you can check if Postfix was
>   compiled with support for Dovecot SASL by running the command:
>
> ```
> postconf -a
> ```
>
> Once you have verified that your installation of Postfix supports....
>   Dovecot SASL

The output I get is:

```
cyrus
dovecot
```

Well, it might be a trivial question to some, but how do you verify the Dovecot SASL support? Does the `dovecot` output means it support Dovecot SASL? If not, what output should there be to indicate it?

Debian Jessie, Dovecot 2.2.13, Postfix 2.11.3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `postconf(1)` man page (which you should read) explains:

```
       -a     List  the available SASL server plug-in types.  The SASL plug-in
              type is selected with the smtpd_sasl_type configuration  parame‐
              ter by specifying one of the names listed below.

              cyrus  This  server  plug-in  is available when Postfix is built
                     with Cyrus SASL support.

              dovecot
                     This  server  plug-in  uses  the  Dovecot  authentication
                     server,  and  is available when Postfix is built with any
                     form of SASL support.

              This feature is available with Postfix 2.3 and later.
```